# sum a sequence of frames using opencv/c++

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I want to sum all values in 4 frames in real-time. current frame and 3 frames before that. To do that, every time that current farme is produced, I store it in a vector called Nframe. This is what I have done until now but seems incorrect..

```
float *amp;   //points to the current frame
vector<float *>Nframe;

   for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
           Nframe.push_back(amp);
        }

         int sum_of_elems=0;
         for(std::vector<int>::iterator j=Nframe.begin();j!=Nframe.end();++j){
         sum_of_elems += *j;
         }
```

Comment: is it not `push_back(*amp)`?

Comment: what do you mean? it is not correct?

Comment: can you show the declaration of `NFrames`?

Comment: vector<float *>Nframe;

Comment: "but seems incorrect.." - that is a very vague statement. incorrect how? does the program not compile? if so, what compiler errors do you get? does it not run? If so, what errors does it give? Or don't you get the expected behavior - and if the latter, what is the output you get and what do you expect?

Comment: i think its iterator mismatch.. `std::vector<int>::iterator j = Nframe.begin();` makes me think `iterator to int = iterator to pointer to float` which is wrong

Comment: I get error in this line:  for(std::vector<int>::iterator j=Nframe.begin();j!=Nframe.end();++j)...and I do not now even the algorithm is correct or not

Comment: @Koushik: do you know how should I write it?

Comment: what do you want to do in the sum of elements?

Comment: @user3091192 check the answer i've given it might help you

Comment: @Koushik: I want to find their averages...what I am doing is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem is

`std::vector<int>::iterator j=Nframe.begin();`

it is basically **saying pointer to int = pointer to pointer to float**

i.e `iterator to int = iterator to float*`

which is wrong.

change to something like this

```
float sum_of_elems=0.0; // make it float
     for(std::vector<float*>::iterator j=Nframe.begin();j!=Nframe.end();++j){// make iterator to float*
     sum_of_elems += **j;
```

Comment: I did not get any error, but still does not know if it works fine or not..about the whole algorithm..what I am doing is correct? in real-time video processing point of view..?

Comment: that i cant say unless i know what you are doing..this piece of code is ok and it add 4 floats. but other that that i have no idea. sorry. also when you say frames should it not mean a image?

Answer (score 0):

Variable amp is defined as pointer to float. So I suppose that vector Nframe is defined (or should be defined) as `std::vector<float *>`

In this case the code will look the following way

```
     float sum_of_elems = 0.0f;
     for ( auto value : Nframe ) sum_of_elems += *value;
```

Comment: where "value" should be declared?

Comment: It is so-called the range-based for statement. Your compiler should support the C++ 2011 Standard. You can change the loop to the following: for ( std::vector<float *> it = Nframe.begin(); it != Nframe.end(); ++it ) sum_of_elems += *it;